# query for all Queues for a specific User

Tags: apex, search

I want the following functionality: As a user I want to search for another user, find him and find all the related Queues in which he is in, until now I implemented the Search box.

```
public class Search_For_User
{
String keyword;
List<user> results;

public String getkeyword(){
return keyword;
}

public List<user> getresults(){
return results;
}

public void setkeyword(String input){
keyword = input;
}

public PageReference searchUser(){
results = (List<User>)[FIND :keyword IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING USER(FirstName, LastName, ProfileId)][0];
return null;
}
}


<apex:page controller="Search_For_User">
<apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock tabStyle="Account">
        <apex:inputText value="{!keyword}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!searchUser}"/>

        <Apex:pageblockTable value="{!results}" var="r">
              <apex:column value="{!r.FirstName}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!r.LastName}"/>
              <apex:column value="{!r.ProfileId}"/>
        </Apex:pageblockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

How to also find the Queues for the user which i find in the search box?

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at answer provided in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008o6bIAA)

Also take a look at fields of [Group](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_group.htm?search_text=QueueMember) and [GroupMember](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm?search_text=QueueMember) objects to easily form your SOQL query

Comment: I'm not able to build the Query... I need a query to fetch all the queues for the user with id='0051i0000012ogrAAA'...

Answer (score 0):

Make an additional query on `groupMember`, which acts as a kind of junction object between User and Group.

So you can take the User Ids you get returned from your query on Users, use that to construct a query that will return all of the groupMembers with group name/id:

```
public PageReference searchUser(){
results = (List<User>)[FIND :keyword IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING USER(FirstName, LastName, ProfileId)][0];

Id[] idList = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, User>(results).keySet());
GroupMember[] groupMembers = [SELECT Group.Name, GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId IN :idList ];
```

You can then take the `groupMembers` result and create some sort of data structure, a wrapper class, and associate the group with the User based on the Id.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that advanced in coding.  Right now my method looks like this and this error: List has no rows for assignment to SObject 

 public PageReference searchUser(){
    results = (List<User>)[FIND :keyword IN NAME FIELDS RETURNING USER(FirstName, LastName, ProfileId)][0];
    Id[] idList = new List<Id>(new Map<Id, User>(results).keySet());
    GroupMember[] groupMembers = [SELECT Group.Name, GroupId, UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE UserOrGroupId IN :idList];
    System.Debug(groupMembers);
    return null;
    }

Comment: Never mind, it works :)